# Chrome history - How reliable are the date and timestamps?

Tags: google-chrome

Ive caught someone looking at my gmail emails. How reliable are the date & timestamps on Google Chrome History? This is really important as I need to prove it.

Comment: How do you prove reliability?

Answer (score 0):

I've conducted a number of investigations involving browser history over the years and have never found any evidence that they are inaccurate *unless* the operating system datetime is itself inaccurate, which is very uncommon on a modern Internet-connected computer. However, if the system datetime is/was incorrect at the time of access, the Chrome browser history would report the same incorrect datetime.

I consulted with a colleague in IT Security who has performed more rigorous investigations than I have, and he concurred that these datetime stamps are generally considered reliable and accepted as good forms of evidence in investigations he has conducted. Chrome browser history is very commonly examined and collected by digital forensics tools used by law enforcement professionals.

Please note however that neither I nor my colleague are trained legal investigators, so I cannot conclusively say that this evidence would be accepted as fact in a court of law in your jurisdiction.

Finally, from a pragmatic standpoint: if you intend to present this evidence to an internal company investigation, then it's really down to the person you are presenting it to as to whether they accept the evidence as reliable or not. From personal experience, I have not been challenged on the validity of such evidence during internal investigations. However, if this will be presented as part of a legal investigation, **consult a lawyer**.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth reply J. Schlackman, it has definitely helped steer me in the right direction.